# Adding a custom validation for a character field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose i am defining a character field in the model like this -

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I want to validate the name entry for some specific names like -

```
name_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: can you explain exactly which validation you want to check for name field of your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the argument `choices` as described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices

The example from there:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. It was one of my personal project. I was kept away from doing it due to my office projects. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom `clean_name` method in your form. For example

```
......
def clean_name(self):
    name_list = ['foo', 'bar']
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['name'] not in name_list:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Name is not in the list.')
    return cd['name']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.